# PHP function mysqli_bind_param error with parameters

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to learn the usage of new mysqli functions (earlier I was using mysql_* in procedural style). I'm developing a very simply query from a MySQL database: I want to fetch all the rows in the provautenti table, where name starts with L letter.

```
$risultati = $conn->prepare("select * from provautenti where nome like '?%'");
                $letteracercata = 'l';
                $risultati->bind_param('s', $letteracercata);
                $risultati->execute();
                $risultati->store_result();
                if ($risultati->num_rows > 0) {
                    echo '<tr><td>id</td><td>nome</td><td>indirizzo</td><td>professione</td></tr><tr>';
                    $risultati->bind_result($id, $nome, $indirizzo, $professione);
                    while ($risultati->fetch())
                        echo '<tr><td>'.$id.'</td><td>'.$nome.'</td><td>'.$indirizzo.'</td><td>'.$professione.'</td></tr>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                }
                else
                    echo 'Nessun risultato';
                $risultati->close();
```

The error is:

```
mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement
```

I don't know why... there only a ? and I'm passing a unique param... where's the problem?

Comment: That's not how parameters work. You have zero (valid) parameters, and one variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put a parameter in a string. So it's not a valid parameter.

Try:

```
"SELECT * FROM provautenti WHERE nome LIKE CONCAT( ? ,'%')"
```